# why this program is crashing

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I wrote a small program in which, I want to set the value of a frame to 255 based on a  vector:

```
result =    cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(),CV_8UC1);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> imageCorners;
.......................................................
    for ( int i = 0 ; imageCorners.size();i++){
                std::cout << imageCorners[i]<< std::endl;
                result.at<uchar>(imageCorners[i]) = 255;
                cv::imshow("result",result);
            }
```

my question is: why the program crashes just after finishing the loop ?? even I see that result is correct ? the error message that I get is :

```
vector subscript out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ( int i = 0 ; imageCorners.size();i++){
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The underlined part is the *condition*. In this case you are saying "keep looping until the size of `imageCorners` is "false" (i.e. `0`)". But you never change the size of the vector, so this condition never stops the loop, `i` keeps getting bigger, until you try to access an index that isn't actually in `imageCorners`.

Presumably you mean to loop until `i` gets bigger than the vector. Then use

```
for (int i=0; i < imageCorners.size(); ++i) {
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks dodgy to me:

```
 for ( int i = 0 ; imageCorners.size();i++){
```

you surely wanted to write something like:

```
 for ( int i = 0 ; i < imageCorners.size();i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition of your loop, `imageCorners.size()` only yields the number of elements stored in the container. The statement will always evaluate to `true` as soon as you put one element into `imageCorners`. What you want is `i < imageCorners.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = 0 ; imageCorners.size();i++)
```

I think this loop will run forever if imageCorners.size() is different than 0. So when this

```
std::cout << imageCorners[i]<< std::endl;
```

gets executed, at some point `i` will be out of bounds and the program will crash.